# Async function not behaving as I expect with Jest

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, jestjs

The Javascript Jest testing framework [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html) says that I need to add `done()` in my callback to test an asynchronous function, as otherwise the function will return after the test completes and so the test will fail. I have Jest added to my package.json, and the following two files:

src.js:

```
function fetchData(cb) {
  setTimeout(cb, 2000, 'peanut butter')
}

module.exports = fetchData
```

src.test.js:

```
const fetchData = require('./src')

test('the data is peanut butter', () => {
  function callback(data) {
    expect(data).toBe('peanut butter')
    // no done() method!
  }

  fetchData(callback);
})
```

I get passing tests with the above code, but I think I should get a failing test since I don't have `done()` in my test file. Is my `fetchData()` method not asynchronous?

---

**EDIT:** Following Nicholas' answer, I changed the code to this:

src.js:

```
function fetchData(cb) {
  setTimeout(cb, 2000, 'peanut')
}

module.exports = fetchData
```

src.test.js:

```
const fetchData = require('./src')

test('the data is peanut butter', () => {
  function callback(data) {
    expect(data).toBe('peanut butter')
    done()
  }

  fetchData(callback);
})
```

The test runner should evaluate the expectation/assertion per the Jest documentation and fail (**peanut** being passed, **peanut butter** expected), but still shows a passing test.

Also, the Jest documentation says:

```
If done() is never called, the test will fail, which is what you want to happen
```

The test passes both with and without the `done()` method in the callback, and both with and without a correct (`peanut butter`) argument passed to the callback (i.e. all four variants pass).

Comment: If you don't pass `done` as an argument the code is considered synchronous and doesn't wait. The test is considered succesful *before* your assertions get a chance to run

Comment: It doesn't matter how long I set the timer for, the test runner waits for the timer to finish before reporting the test results in my console. But the docs say I need to do something special to handle async code - and the expectation object is definitely being executed asynchronously (as a callback to `setTimeout()`)

Comment: the test runner (or more specifically Node itself) waits for the last registered `setTimeout` callback to expire before terminating the process. Try creating an empty file and put just a `setTimeout` in it. You'll see that it won't exit the process until it fires

Comment: Jest has a total gotcha where it modifies the behaviour of the timing functions. I've edited my answer to include a working example and a reference to the Issue that discusses that behavior

Comment: also again, in the edit you included, you are not passing `done` as an argument to `test`. `done` should be also passed as an argument, apart from also getting called when you're done with your test. Have a look at my example, run it and you'll get the point. Pay attention to line 8, where I pass `test` as an argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't pass `done` as an argument, the test runner considers the code synchronous and doesn't wait for something special to occur - in this case invoking `done`.

Therefore, the test is marked as succesful *before* your assertions/expectations get a chance to run.

Comment: That makes sense. But testing doesn't confirm it - I changed the string in src.js to just `peanut` (the third argument to `setTimeout()`), and I still get passing tests with both variants (with and without the `done()` method in the test callback, as shown in the Jest documentation). Any ideas on why?

Comment: If you're passing but not calling `done` the test should timeout after some time. In Mocha which is what I use, it timeouts after 2000ms by default if `done` is not called

Comment: That works. I think I'll open a bug report - they're showing in the issue you reference (#3211) that `done()` can be used in place of `jest.useFakeTimers()` inside the callback. I can't think why that work - it seems like the test runner would be finished, as you mention - but they mention it both in that thread and their docs.

Comment: Overwriting these native functions is a big no-no in my book. They could have created their own timing functions instead, which would avoid half this question and our time in the first place. As for `done is never called should fail the test`, this only applies if you actually pass `if done` as an argument, which you did not in any of your examples. Hope that helps

Comment: Jest doesn't overwrite the timers by default, but it provides `jest.useFakeTimers()` to *mock* the timers for manual (fine-grained) control. See [Guides - Timer Mocks](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/timer-mocks.html).

Comment: Then how comes `setTimeout` in my example - where it's declared directly in the spec file, doesn't tick unless I do what I do with `useFakeTimers()`/`runAllTimers()`?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides In your example the `expect(data).toBe('foo butter')` assertion fails, which throws and therefore the `done()` line is not reached. Precisely because Jest doesn't hijack `setTimeout` (unless you use `jest.uesFakeTimers`) it doesn't know that it threw. A workaround is shown in [#2980](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2980). This problem doesn't occur with promises, because if the assertion throws in the `.then`, callback, the promise will be rejected and it indicates a failure.

Comment: you are right - can you edit your answer to include the info you just posted in your comment?

Answer (score 1):

Your `fetchData` is asynchronous on its own and Jest has no influence on that. On the other hand, Jest needs to know when a test finishes, which is generally when the test functions exits, but that only covers synchronous code. In your case, when your test function exits, you haven't called any assertions and Jest considers this a success (because there was no failure).

To demonstrate that no assertion was called, I will use [`expect.assertions(number)`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#expectassertionsnumber) to only pass the test if it called exactly `number` assertions. For example if you set it to 1 in your example:

```
test('the data is peanut butter', () => {
  // Require exactly 1 assertion to pass the test
  expect.assertions(1)

  function callback(data) {
    expect(data).toBe('peanut butter')
  }

  fetchData(callback)
})
```

You will see the error message:

```
● the data is peanut butter

  expect.assertions(1)

  Expected one assertion to be called but received zero assertion calls.
```

As you can see, no assertion was called. Apart from the demonstration purpose, you could use `expect.assertions` to make sure your test fails when the assertions weren't called.

For any asynchronous tasks, you need to let Jest know that the test is asynchronous and you need to notify Jest when it finished. One way is with the `done` callback. When your test function takes one argument (usually called `done`), Jest will treat it as an asynchronous test and wait until you call the `done()` callback, or when the timeout threshold is reached (default: 5s). In your edited example your function takes zero arguments, and your call to `done()` is not Jest's callback.

```
test('done callback', done => {
  //                  ^^^^ 1 argument
  // Jest waits until this callback is called or the timeout was reached.
  // ...
})

test('no callback argument', () => {
  //                         ^^ no argument
  // Test finishes as soon as the function exits
  // ...
})
```

This is rarely used anymore, because promises are much more common nowadays and they make this a lot simpler, as you can return the promise and Jest will wait for its completion without any extra setup. Additionally, you can use `async` and `await` to make it even nicer, as it's syntactic sugar on top of promises.

See also [Testing Asynchronous Code - Promises](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html#promises) and [Testing Asynchronous Code - Async/Await](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html#async-await)

Comment: This answer doesn't really indicate what the problem is with the OP's current code and delves into very superfluous info.

Comment: It was only talking about the assertions not being called. But I edited it to clarify that `expect.assertions` is used for demonstration purposes.